# Function "creat" in libc

Tags: libc, rtems

I'm trying to build **RTEMS** (www.rtems.org) for my **MicroBlaze** processor, but I have an error that I can't fix.

When using `autoconf`, the file `conftest.c` is generated and requires function `creat()` in libc. But, libc does not have the function `creat()`, so it fails with an error.

Does anyone knows why this function is missing, and how can I fix it ?

Comment: creat() used to exist but is now [obsoleted](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-and-Closing-Files.html) Are you using an old version of RTEMS? In my memories RTEMS leader Joel Sherrill used to be part of GCC steering committee. GCC is not libc, but still...

Comment: I use version 4.10.99.0 (because I need a BSP for the Microblaze processor, and I found this repository : https://github.com/heshamelmatary/rtems-microblaze)
Do you think it's a too old one ? And have you a solution to add creat() to libc ?

Comment: Well, last commit is 8 month old, but I would not consider this "old" by RTEMS pace. Of course you installed a RTEMS toolchain (including a libc) that suit your target, check if it has a creat(), and a functionnal one: I an able to use a creat() in dummy code using my host toolchain, but it always yeld an error. In any case, you'd better ask in the rtems mailing list. It's a small but knowledgeable community. Here on SO, only 29 questions tagged "rtems"...

Comment: I installed a RTEMS toolchain (including a libc) that suit my target, but it has not creat()... 
I already asked in the rtems mailing list, and waiting for an answer, but I also tried on SO :)